# 'Error updating tree format' when using iOS SoundAnalysis Framework

Tags: ios, swift, coreml, createml

I'm using the [SoundAnalysis framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/soundanalysis) in conjunction with a CoreML model I created using CreateML.

I was able to use [SNAudioFileAnalyzer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/soundanalysis/snaudiofileanalyzer) to perform an analysis on audio files embedded in the app bundle, but not when using [SNAudioStreamAnalyzer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/soundanalysis/snaudiostreamanalyzer) on live audio from the microphone.

when using the code below:

```
    // Create a new audio engine.
    audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()

    //https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/44833
    audioEngine.mainMixerNode

    do {
        // Start the stream of audio data.
        try audioEngine.start()
    } catch {
        print("Unable to start AVAudioEngine: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // Get the native audio format of the engine's input bus.
    let inputFormat = audioEngine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)

    // Create a new stream analyzer.
    var streamAnalyzer = SNAudioStreamAnalyzer(format: inputFormat)
```

I'm getting an error at the last line of:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error updating tree format'
```

Anyone have any idea? Right now there isn't much written about the SoundAnalysis Framework, so feeling somewhat out in the woods on this one.

Comment: Are you using the `main thread` ? apparently SNAudioStreamAnalyser need the main thread

Comment: @ThomasBesnehard yes; all that code is inside a method that gets called from viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got ride of the error by setting `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord)`

Comment: Yup, that seems to solve that particular issue so marked as correct (though now getting a different error of: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: inputNode != nullptr || outputNode != nullptr')

Comment: I also got this error :-) It means your engine doesn't have any input or output when you start it.

In my case, I had the error because I was calling `audioEngine.start()` before `audioEngine.inputNode.installTap()`

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error, it seam to be around `let inputFormat = audioEngine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)`, but no more info for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error, pretty obvious for my case this was because I was testing on simulator with no built-in microphone input. I got rid of this once I switched to real device.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same exception with very similar init code running on the simulator. For me the problem disappeared after I simply restarted the simulator (Device > Restart).